# Trouble with double-linked list

Tags: c, list, doubly-linked-list

So I got this task to make a program which will allow the user to enter a number of integer elements in a double-linked list and I have to delete the ones which can be divided (remainder 0) with the sum of their digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NEW(t) (t*)malloc(sizeof(t))

typedef int info_t;

typedef struct element {
  info_t info;
  struct element *next;
  struct element *prev;
} node;

typedef node* nodep;
void insert(nodep l, info_t x) {
  nodep t = NEW(node);
  t->info=x;
  t->next=l->next;
  l->next=t;
  t->prev=l;
}
void printList(nodep l) {
  nodep t=l->next;
  while(t!=l)
  {
      printf("->%d", t->info);
      t=t->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
void deletedividable(nodep l) {
  nodep t=l->next;
  nodep temp;
  while(t->next!=l)
  {
      int temporary=t->info;
      int sum=0;
      while(temporary>0)
      {
          sum+=(temporary%10);
          temporary/=10;
      }
      if(!(t->info%sum))
      {
          temp=t->next;
          t->next->prev=t->prev;
          t->prev->next=t->next;
          free(t);
          t=temp;
      }
      else
        t=t->next;
   }
}

int main() {
  // declaring a leader node
  nodep list = NEW(node);
  list->next = list;
  list->prev = list;

  printf("Enter elements:\n ");
  int a;
  //if the input isn't a number the loop will exit
  while(scanf("%d", &a)) {
    //elements input function call
    insert(list, a);
  }
  // print list function call
  printList(list);
  // delete elements which are dividable with the sum of their digits

  deletedividable(list);

  printList(list);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, after the deletedividable(list); function call, nothing is printed when the second printlist is called and I can't seem to locate the problem, some of the pointers must be getting screwed up, but I'm not sure which ones.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Homework? Interview question?

Comment: Nope, actually I'm practicing for an exam next week :)

Comment: Also, you have a nice `insert` function. Why not make a `delete` or `remove` function to go with it and then use it in `deletedividable`. Easier to test small parts.

Comment: Basically it's the same algorithm, but I've tried that and I get the same problem.

Comment: And in C you don't need to cast the return value of malloc. It is void* and will automatically become whatever it is assigned to.

Comment: This is a learning experience for you! Now you have to learn how to debug. :-) Options: printf statements, a debugger, or visual code inspection. In this case I recommend printf.

Comment: it looks more like circular double linked list to me. be careful for case when there are 1 or two elements.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on casting. :)

Comment: Just so you know, this is common in production too. I often have to wade through a gigabyte sized debug log file in order to find the one out-of-place item in it. Debuggers cannot be used on live code.

Comment: And yeah it's a circular double linked list but I don't think that would be any different from having a NULL pointer at the end...

Comment: I have put a printf in the if(!(t->info%sum)) check and it looks like each second element that satisfies the condition is jumped... but I'm still not sure what could be wrong :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems an error exists in your `insert()` function. A hint: insertion into a circular double-linked list should set or change 4 pointers; you only set 3.

Comment: +1 - though I'd say "up to 4" pointers, as two updates are normally conditional, only occurring if certain other pointer aren't null, and I don't see the null checks above. There are exceptions to that, though, such as cyclic lists and using sentinel objects, and I didn't check that code very carefully.

Comment: @Steve314: the list is circular with a sentinel node, so no null checks and 4 pointers should be set. But you are right for the general case.

Comment: Lol what a silly mistake on my side, I have forgotten to set the prev pointer of the next node after l to point at the new node.
l->next->prev=t;